# Exibir primeira imagem de uma tabela dinâmica em php

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber como exibo a primeira imagem da minha tabela do MySQL?

Eu utilizei uma input file dinâmico, então, posso ter vários nomes salvos em uma única tabela que no caso é a imagem. No entanto, eu gostaria de saber como eu exibo somente a primeira?

Os nomes no BD estão separados por `;`

```
<div class="lista-prod col-lg-12 ">
<?php 
   $verificaQuery = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from produtos");
   $verificaRow = mysqli_num_rows($verificaQuery);

       if ($verificaCount = 0) {

       } else {
           $contProd=0;
           while ($contSql = mysqli_fetch_array($verificaQuery)) {
            $contProd++;
       ?>
<div class="row mt-5">
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <img src="../imagens/produtos/<?php echo $contSql['imagem'];  ?>" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

Se eu cadastro apenas uma imagem ela aparece normalmente, porém, se cadastro mais, ela some. Para resumir, eu tenho uma pagina produtos, a primeira imagem é a que fica amostra caso a pessoa abre o produto, exibe as outras fotos ao lado, como eu controlo isso?

Comment: `<?php echo explode(';', $contSql['imagem'])[0]; ?>`

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso, obrigado Thiago

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo com a resposta do comentário, vou deixar logo abaixo um outro exemplo de codigo com maior organização:

```
<div class="lista-prod col-lg-12 ">
    <?php 
        $verificaQuery = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from produtos");
        $verificaRow = mysqli_num_rows($verificaQuery);
        if ($verificaRow != 0) {    
           while ($contSql = mysqli_fetch_array($verificaQuery)) {
              $arrayDeImagens = explode(';', $contSql['imagem']);
              $primeiraImagem = $arrayDeImagens[0];
              echo "<div class='row mt-5'>
                       <div class='col-lg-4'>
                           <img src='../imagens/produtos/$primeiraImagem' style='width:100%;'>
                       </div>
                    </div>"; 
           }
        }            
    ?>
</div>
```

O código ira imprimir o HTML com o `src` da tag `img` sendo a primeira imagem de cada linha retornada